# Is there any way to use different scheduler for distinct parameter groups in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Consider that we have the following `Pytorch` classes:

```
class NN1(nn.Module):

 # Any parameters


class NN2(nn.Module):

 # Any parameters
```

Now, we want to train them but with different learning rates. Therefore, we define:

```
module1 = NN1()
module2 = NN2()

criterion = nn.MSELoss() # Mean Square Error Loss
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([ 
                {'params': module1.parameters(), 'lr':0.2},
                {'params': module2.parameters(), 'lr': 0.1}
            ])
```

Finally, we want different adaptive learning rates for each group of parameters, but I couldn't find any solutions.

For example, I want exponential adaptive learning rate with `gamma = 0.8` and `gamma = 0.9` for the `module1` and `module2`, respectively. If one uses the following, it will decay both learning rates with the same `gamma=0.9`.

```
scheduler = ExponentialLR(optimizer, gamma=0.9, verbose = True)
```

I found this question on GitHub https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/issues/4983, but it uses a different type of Pytorch scheduler.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implemented custom scheduler - [github](https://github.com/kardasbart/MultiLR) - that handles multiple pytorch's schedulers as an input. This is super simple workaround. It can be used as follows:

```
scheduler = MultiLR(optimizer, 
            [lambda opt: torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(opt, step_size=10, gamma=0.5), 
             lambda opt: torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LinearLR(opt, start_factor=0.25, total_iters=10)])
```

Just implement lambda scheduler factory for each parameter group and pass them to the constructor.